# Purpose for bonobo-etl Tee node

Tags: bonobo-etl

A [tee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) operation is expected to take an input and return two copy outputs.

I noticed that bonobo-etl [features Tee nodes](https://github.com/python-bonobo/bonobo/blob/29d07aa5f1a2c07974449ec8335f01ad5591b619/bonobo/nodes/basics.py#L62), but it's not clear how they are intended to be used.

Can they be used to fork the running graph into two directions?
Or are they intended for a Load-type persistent action, to use without stopping the data flow in that particular node?

Answer (score 0):

The `bonobo.Tee(f: Callable)` operation just applies a function and pass the stream input unmodified into the stream output.

Although the name obviously comes from the unix tool `tee` (as you pointed), it's not perfectly similar as in the bonobo version, one output is the stream output and one output is just the callable you use. This callable may or may not send data to a stream (and sending data to a stream is knid of hackish for now).

As an example, if you use `Tee(print)`, then there will be the stream passed both to output and `print`.

As another, more realistic example, you should be able to do the following:

```py
import bonobo
import queue

output_queue = queue.Queue()


def get_graph():
    graph = bonobo.Graph()
    graph >> range(100) >> bonobo.Tee(output_queue.put) >> print
    return graph


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with bonobo.parse_args() as options:
        bonobo.run(get_graph())

    while True:
        try:
            print("out:", output_queue.get_nowait())
        except queue.Empty:
            break
```

Hope that helps.